# Duplicate files copied in APK Android

Tags: android, gradle, dl4j

I'm having this "Duplicate files copied in APK" problems when trying to compile my Android project.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86/msvcp120.dll
    File1: C:\Users\yuh5\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets\opencv\3.1.0-1.3\3d455d0c218e90072827d5b22b4163b1eea323e9\opencv-3.1.0-1.3-windows-x86.jar
    File2: C:\Users\yuh5\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets\hdf5\1.10.0-patch1-1.3\76b579910f51cd628bed8f6cbb245670483b9eeb\hdf5-1.10.0-patch1-1.3-windows-x86.jar
```

It says it's because msvcp120.dll is included in two places, but I don't know what and how to do the 'exclude' or 'pickfirst' to get rid of this error.

My gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yuh5.nih.testall"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile project(':libraries:opencv')
    compile ('org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:0.8.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.8.0'
    compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native:0.8.0:android-arm'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in `packagingOptions` :

```
 pickFirst 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86/msvcp120.dll'
```

Comment: So how do I get the path correct? I tried both: exclude 'META-INF/msvcp120.dll' and exclude  'META-INF/org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86/msvcp120.dll'. But none of them work.

Comment: Just use the exclude as a put it, with the stars

Comment: What about `pickFirst 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86/msvcp120.dll'` ?

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much! There are three other files I need to do the same thing to, so the complete answer is: `pickFirst 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86/msvcp120.dll'
        pickFirst 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86_64/msvcp120.dll'
        pickFirst 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86/msvcr120.dll'
        pickFirst 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86_64/msvcr120.dll'`

Comment: Hi @ToYonos, I'm wondering if you also use dl4j in your Android project? If so, what do you think on why there is no post out there asking this question? Is it because it's so easy that people can just figure it out on their own?

Comment: You are just the first to ask the question here I guess (i am not using it)